# How to reference class from an authorization handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this filter and I want to reference a class to use its method. However, I can't seem to use it within RoleVerificationHandler or even reference the method.

This is how its referenced in Startup.cs. I'm not sure how to inject the class reference in here as well.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("SystemAdministrator", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new RolesFilter("SystemAdministrator", ApplicationGlobals.ApplicationName)));
});
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, RoleVerificationHandler>();
```

RolesFilter class

```
public class RolesFilter : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public String Role { get; set; }
    public String ApplicationName { get; set; }
    private DecodeToken decodeToken { get; set; }

    public RolesFilter(String Role,String ApplicationName, DecodeToken decodeToken)
    {
        this.Role = Role;
        this.ApplicationName = ApplicationName;
        this.decodeToken = decodeToken;
    }
}

public class RoleVerificationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RolesFilter>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RolesFilter requirement)
    {
        //get roles based on app id, then check if the user has the correct role
        var roles = context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "Roles").Select(c => c.Value).ToList();
        foreach(var item in roles)
        {
            var currentItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserRoleDetailsViewModel>(item);
            UserRoleDetailsViewModel urdvm = new UserRoleDetailsViewModel
            {
                Id = currentItem.Id,
                Name = currentItem.Name,
                ApplicationId = currentItem.ApplicationId,
                ApplicationName = currentItem.ApplicationName
            };
            if(requirement.Role == urdvm.Name && urdvm.ApplicationName == ApplicationGlobals.ApplicationName)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }

        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: explicitly inject the desired dependency into the `RoleVerificationHandler` via constructor injection. [Dependency injection in requirement handlers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/dependencyinjection?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly inject the desired dependency into the `RoleVerificationHandler` via constructor injection.

Reference [Dependency injection in requirement handlers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/dependencyinjection?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

> Authorization handlers must be registered in the service collection during configuration (using dependency injection).
>   .....

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, RoleVerificationHandler>();
```

> An instance of the handler will be created when your application starts, and DI will inject your registered dependency into your handler's constructor.

```
public class RoleVerificationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RolesFilter> {
    private readonly IMyDependency dependency;

    public RoleVerificationHandler(IMyDependency dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RolesFilter requirement)
    {
        //get roles based on app id, then check if the user has the correct role
        var roles = context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "Roles").Select(c => c.Value).ToList();
        foreach(var item in roles) {
            var currentItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserRoleDetailsViewModel>(item);
            UserRoleDetailsViewModel urdvm = new UserRoleDetailsViewModel {
                Id = currentItem.Id,
                Name = currentItem.Name,
                ApplicationId = currentItem.ApplicationId,
                ApplicationName = currentItem.ApplicationName
            };
            if(requirement.Role == urdvm.Name && urdvm.ApplicationName == ApplicationGlobals.ApplicationName) {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }    
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```